# WCF service response from "html" to "xml"

Tags: html, xml, wcf, response, svc

trying to translate from one asmx web service to svc web service. same code, but got the following difference in responce

when using asmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.MyKidsSpending.com/">-2202.68</string>
```

when using svc:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">-2202.68</string>
```

where did the first line go? 
Here is the fist couple of lines of the function that I am testing in the svc service....

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public string Balance(string Uid)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

I was suggested that the response was html, that is why it doesn't have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

now I change text/html to text/xml, why doesn't still match? Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: which binding is configured in your service? you can also include your namespace in the contract, using this:
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.MyKidsSpending.com/")]

Comment: where would I change this? I am using visual studio

Comment: where you declare your interface. Your interface must have a ServiceContract attribute